# polymerfire/firebase-auth email verification not working

Tags: authentication, polymer, firebase-authentication, email-verification, polymerfire

I am using firebase-auth (of polymerfire).  Here is my element:

```
<firebase-auth id="auth" user="{{user}}"></firebase-auth>
```

I can observe changes on user when I login, so that part works fine.  My problem is that for some reason I can't observe changes to `user` when I verify my email.  Here are my observers:

```
  properties: {
    user: {
      observer: '_obsUser'
    }
  },
  observers: [
    '_obsUser(user.*)'
  ],
```

I added the second observer just to make sure I observed all changes on the `user`.  Again, no observer is triggered when I verify my email address.  I even added a button to check the `emailVerified` property of `user` after I verified and it is still false.

Here is my check button I added:

```
<paper-button on-tap="_check">Check Verify</paper-button>
```

and the check function:

```
  _check: function(){
    console.log(this.user.emailVerified);
  },
```

Even though the user has verified, `_check` still returns false.

If I reload my polymer app, the `emailVerified` prop will be true.  But for some reason `user` that is bound is not updating properly without a hard reload.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen .  Any ideas?

Comment: emailVerified will not update its status without an explicit reload. Are you reloading the user after he/she is verified?